# How to weigh percentage versus quantity?

Tags: math, percentage, rating

So I have a leader board I'm trying to develop and I've run into a bit of a problem...
It's a roulette game and I want to show who was the best stats.

Lets look at the following examples for scores:

21 wins, 15 losses
40 wins, 1 loss
40 wins, 10 losses
10 wins, 0 losses
1 win, 0 losses

In my mind the leader board should be like so:

#1 40 wins, 1 loss
 #2 10 wins, 0 losses
 #3 1 win, 0 losses
 #4 40 wins, 10 losses
 #5 21 wins, 15 losses

Originally I was going with just percentage but that means 1 win 0 losses beats 40 wins and 1 loss which doesn't make sense to me. I'm trying to find a way to weight quantity vs percentage.

I was originally thinking:

%*total = score

but that didn't give me a reasonable result, then I tried:

(%)^2*total = score

but again failure...
I know there must be a formula for this somewhere!!!
Help plz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question.  I'd suggest that you create an index which defined as:

```
Index = (Total wins) - Weight * (total losses).
```

With the example you gave, if you set Weight to 4 then the result would be

```
#1 (Index = 36) 40 wins, 1 loss
#2 (Index = 10) 10 wins, 0 losses
#3 (Index = 1) 1 win, 0 losses
#4 (Index = 0) 40 wins, 10 losses
#5 (Index = -39) 21 wins, 15 losses
```

so it would give you the order that you want.  But you can play around with the weight to get the type of ordering that you desire.

Comment: I figured it out. I realized that the chance of winning roulette was 1 in 6 so I measured the score based on how much they were beating those odds with this equation: total*(1/6) - died = score. The first part is how many times they were expected to die minus how many times they did die and what is left is how much they're ahead

Comment: I just realized what you said is exactly what I said, except the weight is 6 instead of 4. You just weighted the deaths when I weighted the wins. Accepted. Thanks.

Comment: LOL yes, I just spotted that too!  Thanks for accepting my answser :-)

Comment: I actually used your equation in the end, cause the final score didn't involve decimals. Good work.